# Want loading symbol until the storage process is completed in isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, isolatedstorage

I have downloaded 200 images from absolute URL and stored in isolated storage. I want to display in my list or stackpanel one by one.I want the stack panel to show loading symbol until the download completes and the 200th image stored in isolated storage.

```
        if (h < 150)
        {

            WebClient m_webClient = new WebClient();

            Uri m_uri = new Uri("http://d1mu9ule1cy7bp.cloudfront.net/2012/media/catalogues/47/pages/p_" + h + "/IKEA_mobile_high.jpg");

            m_webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);

            m_webClient.OpenReadAsync(m_uri);

        }
    }

    void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        int count;

        try
        {
            Stream stream = e.Result;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];


            using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {

                //isf.Remove();


                using (System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("IMAGES" + loop2(k) + ".jpg", FileMode.Create, isf))
                {
                    count = 0;

                    while (0 < (count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)))
                    {
                        isfs.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }

                    stream.Close();
                    isfs.Close();
                }
            }
        }



        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        GetImages();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I want to show the progress bar and show the percentage of completed download process in my page until all the images downloaded in isolated store. I have downloaded the image by the code shown above.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is show the progress of this long running task then simply add a `ProgressBar`. Set it's `Minimum` to 0, it's `Maximum` to 200 (or however many images you're going to download) then as each image download reports completion simply increase the `Value` of the ProgressBar by one.

Once all images have been downloaded (i.e. Value == Maximum) then you know you can remove your loading indicator.

You should probably also think about provding a way for the user to cancel the download and whether you really must download all the images before the app can be used.